# Page layout acting strangely

Tags: html, css

If you go on to my website, [lookaroundyou.net](http://lookaroundyou.net) and click on USA (which is where there are more video's than anywhere else on the site), the websites layout changes completely.

Does anyone have an idea as to why this happens?

Comment: This site is horribly broken. Every time I click on a country name, Firefox freezes up and I have to force close it.

Comment: Rather than giving you more downvotes, I'm going to explain why you're receiving them instead of feedback: Your post is haphazardly thrown together with limited usage of grammar. It is remarkably similar to spam, except that you didn't even [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795420/page-layout-acts-strange) to the page. Please review the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and take some time to tidy up your post. I hope you find stackoverflow a rewarding community.

Comment: thanks dude. will keep it in my mind for next time

Comment: Your page is showing an exception for an unknown MYSQL host... it's also showing your username and password for your MYSQL... might want to fix that ;)

Comment: it seems that my hosting company is doing this. what a pack of lamers. pfff. thanks ;)

Comment: Also, take a look at John Skeet's [Writing the perfect question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) for advice on how to make your future questions more likely to get upvotes and helpful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's causing a scrollbar because there are more videos.

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to visit your site if it's crashing Firefox, but if the problem is indeed due to more content causing a scrollbar to show up and thus changing your page width, one easy way to sort that is to always display a scrollbar (it will be disabled if there is not extra content below).  In this way, the width of the page will be the same regardless of length.

```
<style type="text/css">
html { overflow-y: scroll; }
</style>
```

I'm sure there's some other non-standard setting with IE that will do the same; that's left as an exercise for you.

Comment: that's one nice tip there. many thanks. btw firefox doesn't crashes with me

Answer (score 0):

I'm using chrome and I don't see any difference other than the page shifts when the scrollbar on the right appears.....

Comment: yeah, myself using chrome too. totally haven't noticed that bar. arrgh ;) thanks man